# How to view a web app hosted on ubuntu from another machine?

Tags: networking, server, webserver, webapps

I have a Flask web application which is successfully running on an Ubuntu install Running on **http://127.0.0.1:8050/**.

Now, that machine is CLI only so, *I need to open that website from another machine which has a browser*. How can I achieve that?

Replacing *127.0.0.1* with machine's IP is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, webapplications like Flask will bind to `127.0.0.1` for numerous reasons, like security, SSL, reverse proxies, etc.

The simplest solution would be to **change the binding of the webapp**. When you call `flask run`, simply do this:

```
flask run --host 0.0.0.0
```

This will instruct Flask to bind to the IP address 0.0.0.0, which is a catch-all, allowing you to access Flask from any IP. Note that you will need to allow port 8050 through your firewall for this to work.

Alternatively, you may **use a reverse proxy** like NGINX. This also allows you to change the server port, add SSL certificates, balance server load, and many other features necessary for a production webapp. See [the official NGINX docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) for an example of how to do this. You may also use Apache2's [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html), but my personal recommendation would be NGINX.